# How to silence the "return will never be executed" PER OCCURENCE

Tags: swift3

```
... { [weak self] in
                    guard let s = self else {
                        preconditionFailure()
                        return <- what pragma could I use to silence the warning here
                    }
```

I do not want to use compiler directive to shut the swift compiler up.
I want to specify that I did inspect that warning and this code 
looks acceptable to me. (because I reserve the right to pluck
preconditionFailure() at any time and I have no desire to put return back in afterwards)

Comment: Are you aware that `preconditionFailure` already terminates the program? There is no need for a return.

Comment: Yep. I am aware that preconditionFailure() terminates the program. Consider what will happen if you decide to change preconditionFailure() to assertionFailure()

Comment: Then why are you putting the return there?

Comment: As I said I have zero desire to type it back in if preconditionFailure later morphs into anything else

Comment: You mean you're afraid that as Swift evolves, `preconditionFailure` might not terminate the program? The possibility of that happening is pretty low. Even if it happens, the migrater will probably correct it for you.

Comment: No, I'm saying that I'm lazy and if a have a knee jerk reaction to change preconditionFailure() into another call I do not want to type "return" yet again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150728/discussion-between-anton-tropashko-and-sweeper).

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's not possible to suppress a specific warning since Xcode 8.

You can still use the `-Wunreachable-code` flag, but I'm guessing that silencing every unreachables in the entire program is off the table.

Comment: Yes, silencing them wholesale would be utterly idiotic. Any idea who's the bright bulb behind the xcode 8 "enhancement"?